# command \ctg already defined. or name \end

Tags: latex3, compilation-error

What's wrong that pic. I can't founded.

Please help me[image]

Comment: well something is defining the same command twice. But without code nobody can help you to find the source.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. We cannot help without seeing the actual code you are using. Please edit your .tex document, getting rid of as much as possible while still producing your error. Then post the *entire* code that remains. Also, please read the [introductory material](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) for this site.